How can i suppress this warning?
I can suppose that compiler displays warning because there is return invocation in upper when block
Image with code and warning: https://i.sstatic.net/J5oSE.png
P.S when I delete this branch, compiler show error

Please don't post screenshots of code. Instead include the code as text into your question.

The screenshot of the code is Kotlin and not Java. Please avoid tagging incorrect language.
Regarding the syntax, Kotlin's when returns by default. Is there any specific reason to add return ?

@DevayanSarkar when does not return by default.  That return keyword will make it exit the function in that one case, not just exit the when statement.  Which may end up being a bug (it's definitiely unusual to do so in one case out of 3).  But a when statement doesn't do that by default.

@GabeSechan,
Wouldn't this return the value and item gets assigned on the returned value ?
val item  = when(a) {
    "Apple" -> "Fruit"
    "Car" -> "Vehicle"
    else -> "Unknown"
}


@DevayanSarkar return exists the surrounding function block.  The when you wrote would set a value into a.  The when with a case that says return X will return from the surrounding function and never set a value because the function is no longer being executed.  Notice his code is doing that in one case.

There's a couple things you can do.
1)Ignore the warning.  It's not really important and your app will work fine.
2)Add a lint suppression annotation to the function to suppress this specific warning.
3)Use an else -> throw RuntimeException("Illegal state ${loadType}")  instead of that line.  Having an else will make the when have a case for every possibility and satisfy the compiler.  And the compiler generally doesn't flag else branches as unreachable.
Honestly I'd just ignore it.  It's a strange combo.  Of course I'd also find the early return you do in one case a bit of a smell, it's an unusual way to do things and may cause issues in maintenance of the function.  But I don't know enough about your code to say it's wrong.
